# How do I transfer documents from Google Apps to another Google Account outside of that organization?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-docs, google-workspace-for-business, google-drive-sharing

I have a Google Apps account as part of my school, but I'm going to be graduating shortly. I want to transfer ownership of my documents to my personal Google Drive account. However, when I do so from the sharing dialog, it tells me that I can only transfer ownership of documents to other people inside of my domain. I don't need changes to sync back to my old Apps account, as that will be deleted. 
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this without manually share each document or folder with another account, is to make use of [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/drive) (if enabled by your Google Apps-Administrator) to export your Google Drive-content.

Refer to [Download your data: FAQ](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en&ref_topic=3160813) for more information about Google Takeout.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this to work without wasting my bandwidth. My issue was I had about 750GB in an unlimited Google Drive account on one domain but I had to switch off the domain onto a new account, under a different domain. I didn't want to download 750GB just to upload it again and cripple my network for a few days.

[I found this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/4qrhxd/how_to_sync_data_from_google_drive_a_to_google/d4vqlpo/) which mentions a tool called `rclone` which is available on mostly every platform. If you have OSX brew you can simply `brew install rclone`.

Once you have rclone installed you need to do the following:

1. Share your large folder to your new Google Drive account. You don't have to be the owner on your new account. From the shared tab of the web client, add your big folder of stuff to your drive. This should add a linked folder to your root dictionary of your drive.
2. Setup your NEW drive account in rclone by running `rclone config`. Choose `n` for new remote, and then `7` for Google Drive account. These are subject to change so read the list please. Roll through the config. You shouldn't have to type in anything except a name for the account and it should launch your browser to authenticate. Choose the right account.Follow the menu to exit config
3. Now let's build the command to copy all of our stuff using the API. rclone is very nice to us since it obeys API and retries until it copies everything. Here is a skeleton command: `rclone copy name_of_your_NEW_drive:"sharedFolderName" name_of_your_NEW_drive:"aDifferentSharedFolderName"`

Some important things to note about the command:

- You need to name your destination folder something different than the input. This is as easy as just adding copy or whatever
- You can do cross account transfer however this means you will be downloading files which is not what I wanted.

The command will run for quite a while because as the [rclone docs state](http://rclone.org/drive/) the API limits to 2 files per seconds assuming no overhead. If you have a ton of files (versus five 1TB files..) this will take quite a while but it'll be faster and cleaner than downloading it. rclone will periodically update you on the progress and if you set this up right it should say

`Transferred:      0 Bytes (0 Bytes/s)`

which means that you are not downloading any data!

---

This works far more reliably than some of the Google App Scripts which, to be frank, failed for half of my files while rclone duplicated this for me in just under an hour. When it completes the command should just exit so if you want to just paste in another command after to notify you I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 7 years old post, sorry for being too late.

I was searching for a way to solve this problem as I had to keep the link of the file the same.

The solution that I found is to create a shared drive (Not just a shared folder. [Click here for more](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310352?hl=en)).

1. **Create a shared drive** in your organization (School). Sadly personal accounts can not create these sort of drives, not every organization has the right to do this ([Click here for more](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310351)).

   - You might also look into making an organization yourself that has the right to make shared drives. (In 2021 it requires Business Standard and it is $12USD/user/month currently. You can cancel it, but one payment is neccessary. [Click here for more](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization)). With that you can bypass your organization admins too, as you will be the one to set the rules for that.

   School accounts are able to create shared drives. If you are unable to create one, ask your administrators for help.
2. **Move your files into the shared drive** with your organization account.
3. **Give manager access for your personal account**.
4. **Move your files into your drive** with your personal account.

With that you can transfer those files into your account and keep the link too.

**This only works if you can create shared drives or your admin can and willing to help you with that OR if you are willing to pay.**

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to share the Google doc outside of domain

As workaround,Please follow the steps

(i) select the Google doc you need to share and then click on the more icon  and then chose the download button with your desired format.

(ii) Now go to the other domain and open the Google drive,Click upload and then select desired files by browsing the computer.Once it is selected,It would be uploaded