# Google Drive (Sheets) shared file - move ownership - different domains

Tags: google-sheets, sharing

I'm helping my daughter with her project and started an example of how to create a table using Google Sheets, which I shared with her. She continued on with it but now I want to remove it from my Google Drive and let her have it permanently.

Is there a built-in way to do that?

Something like I release my ownership to her and then I remove the file entry in my Drive but she now owns the file?

Or does she have to download the file and upload it to her account to make it permanently hers?

**Edit:**

I can't transfer ownership, but if the file is shared and I remove the file from my Drive, on the other user's "Drive", they will get a message stating  the owner deleted the shared file, it will soon be gone and to make a copy. A button to copy is provided.

If you are on the same domain, the information at the link works fine. I tested that.

Comment: See [Transfer file ownership - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=en)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. I'm downvoting this question for now as the current version doesn't show a research effort like looking looking for the answer in the at the help articles of the related web app..

Comment: @ruben - thanks for the link! It was going great right up till the point I hit "save changes" and I get: "Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to xxxxx.xxxx. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same domain as the current owner". Perfect.

Comment: Unfortunately the help articles are not clear enough. The alternative is that your daughter makes a copy of the file.

Comment: By the way, could be helpful that you edit your question and mention that you and your daughter are using accounts with different domains.

Comment: Why would I even think that is important.

Comment: Because when users posts questions in this site looking for free help they agree that their post will not be only helpful by themselves but by others too. Editing your question could make it a unique case rather than a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transferring files across from restricted Google Drive account](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67371/transferring-files-across-from-restricted-google-drive-account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not like to transfer ownership between domains. Without domains or within the same domain you could transfer without issue.

You can publish the document and append `/copy` to the shared file URL that will prompt the user to copy it to their drive regardless of domain.

So a URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lrq5sbr-Q_8TFky81OSMFgTO1OnQ8bbN1G05m0q3dVQ/`

becomes `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lrq5sbr-Q_8TFky81OSMFgTO1OnQ8bbN1G05m0q3dVQ/copy`

Comment: When I do the initial share, I see (advanced dialog) a URL like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yykVarc75xJipg72AgF-FWhjbPDX1qKB1Z_CXsntbXc/edit?usp=sharing, So after sharing,  I would have to send that URL replacing the "edit...." part with "copy"?

Comment: Yeah- I think `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yykVarc75xJipg72AgF-FWhjbPDX1qKB1Z_CXsntbXc/copy` would do it.