# Transfer ownership from my personal Google Drive account to Google Suite for Education

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, google-drive-sharing, google-workspace

In my personal Google Drive I have a folder and we are migrating to Google Suite for Education. From my personal user I shared that folder to my new Google Suite user with no problem.

I want to transfer the property (ownership) to my GSuite user so that I could then delete the folder and free up the space of my Personal Drive. I get an error message:

*We are sorry; the property cannot be transferred to "mygooglesuiteaccount". This can only be transferred to a user whose domain is the same as that of the current owner.*

Exporting the files from https://takeout.google.com does not help me because the files of sheets, docs, slides are converted to Microsoft Office format and I want to keep the original Google format. Also, downloading the files to re-upload them with the other user, implies to lost the sharing information.

Did anyone have / have the same problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, there is no way to transfer files between accounts from different domains but you could make copies using your G Suite account.

The basic steps are:

1. Using the personal account, share the files from the personal account to the G Suite Account
2. Using the G Suite account, copy the files

Related

- [Transferring files across from restricted Google Drive account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/67371/88163)